# How to output unicode in C++ without _setmode

Tags: c++, unicode, visual-studio-2013, cout

I'm trying to insert a unicode value, in this case, \u250F, or ┏, to the console output. I have searched around, and people recommending a variety of things. Before we discuss on what I tried, I am using Windows and Visual Studio 2013.

**The main error**

When I try multiple 'fixes', if not specified, I always get the same error:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
Program: ...nts\visual studio 2013\Projects\roguelike\Debug\roguelike.exe
File: f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\stdio\fputc.c
Line: 48

Expression: ((_Stream->_flag & _IOSTRG) || ( fn = _fileno(_Stream), 
((_textmode_safe(fn) ==  _IOINFO_TM_ANSI && !_tm_unicode_safe(fn))))

For more information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, 
see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts

(Press Retry to debug the application)
```

**What I have tried**

I have tried to do all of the following things to output it:

```cpp
std::cout << "\u250F";
```

```cpp
std::wcout << "\u250F";
```

```cpp
std::cout << L"\u250F";
```

```cpp
std::wcout << L"\u250F";
```

```cpp
std::cout << "┏";
```

```cpp
std::wcout << "┏";
```

```cpp
std::cout << L"┏";
```

```cpp
std::wcout << L"┏";
```

**How I tried to tell the console how to output unicode**

```cpp
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
```

Seems to be the problem, really.

```
system("chcp 65001");
```

Doesn't error, but doesn't do anything

```
std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.utf8"));
```

It causes an error of where the parameters are "illegal"

Comment: `fflush(stdout);` `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);` `std::wcout << L"\u250f";` works for me with VC++ 10.

Comment: You can also call the Windows API directly, e.g. [`WriteConsoleW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Following code works for me: 
my ENV: vs2013, win7_x64, system locale is 'English (United States)'

```
SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);
wprintf(L"Interface %s\r\n", pNP->pszwName);   //pszwName is a wchar_t*
```

Another tricks is your console font, does your console font include char character '┏ '?

google 'cmd font fontlink' to add a font to your cmd console.

run 'chcp 65001' in your cmd console before execute your program.

Comment: Calling both `SetConsoleOutputCP` and `_setmode` is counterproductive.

Comment: @Marc.2377 Why?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Solved it by switching the order of my pre-processor commands.

If you have included io.h and fcntl.h this way:

```
#include <fcntl.h>  
#include <io.h>
```

switch them so that they're this way:

```
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
```

Comment: Tried to invert but still get the same assertion error