# c - _setmode function causing debug error

Tags: c, windows, qt

Ok, so after posting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904089/c-doesnt-print-character-correctly) I tried to use the solutions provided in the related questions (particularly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528359/printing-utf-8-strings-with-printf-wide-vs-multibyte-string-literals)) pointed by the community but I had another problem.

When trying to use the `_setmode()` function to change the Windows console to print UTF characters I get a debug error, just like the one posted on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26834947/how-to-output-unicode-in-c-without-setmode). The debug error is as follows:

- Text:

  Debug Assertion Failed!

  Program:
  ...kout-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug\debug\Breakout.exe
  File: f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\stdio\output.c
  Line: 1033

  Expression: ((_Stream->_flag & _IOSTRG) || ( fn = _fileno(_Stream), (
  (_textmode_safe(fn) == _IOINFO_TM_ANSI) &&
  !_tm_unicode_safe(fn))))

  For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

  (Press Retry to debug the application)
- Screenshot:

[image: Debug Assert Failed]

Without the `_setmode()` function I still can't print characters from the upper ASCII Table, like these: "┌──┐". What can I do to solve this problem? The solution to the question with the same problem doesn't work also.

Again, I'm using Qt Creator on Windows, with Qt version 5.5.0 MSVC 64 bits. The compiler is the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0 (amd64).

- Edit:

Here's a small sample code that causes the error:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void)
{
    //Using setmode to force the error
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Upon execution the error appears.

Comment: Perhaps you can post a minimal, complete program that shows the problem?

Comment: Added the sample code!

Comment: In my case it stopped doing it when I found I was still calling a cout instead of a wcout after having called _setmode as you did. Changed to wcout and the assertion error went away.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if you set the output mode to UTF-16, you must then use wprintf instead of printf.

(Presumably, since you have told the runtime to translate from UTF-16, you have to *provide* UTF-16.)

This code runs on my machine:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wprintf(L"\x043a\x043e\x0448\x043a\x0430 \x65e5\x672c\x56fd\n");
    return 0;
}
```

So does

```
wprintf(L"Hello world!\n");
```

*PS* - I'm not sure whether this will solve your underlying problem, which I suspect has to do with the encoding of the source file.  Even if using UTF-16 *does* solve your problem, it probably isn't the best solution.

Comment: It doesn't work, as the program outputs the error regardless of what else happens on it. I tried looking for the encoding but didn't make any progress, I just screwed the representation of some files on the IDE.

Comment: Can you try the code I've just added to my answer?  It works fine for me, except of course my font doesn't contain the Cyrillic characters so I just get question marks.  (But it looks like your original problem has been solved, on the other question?)

Comment: It didn't work. As I said, no matter what else happens on the code, this line causes the error. I accepted the answer on the other question because it makes sense as the origin of the problem, but it didn't solve it nonetheless. I think I'll go back to the workaround.

Comment: I can only assume that Qt is doing something weird then, because in a normal application that code works.